# Swift Get Element From Each Element In JSON Array

Tags: arrays, json, swift, element

So I have a `.json` file that stores an array. When I load the file in swift it is referred to as `trackData`. What I want to do is access the a nested item from `trackData` for every item in this array.

For example, if this were one item from `trackData`:

```
[(id: UUID(), trackdate: DateComponents(year: 2021, month: 4, day: 2), tokencount: 2), (id: UUID(), trackdate: DateComponents(year: 2020, month: 8, day: 4), tokencount: 6)]
```

I want to access the specific year from the DateComponents for every item. In this case there would only be two years that are returned: `2021` and `2020`.

I tried using `forEach` based on what I found online, but I couldn't find any examples for arrays like this in which there is data within each element.

I am fairly new to swift, so this may be something basic that I am simply overlooking. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Please add the code your tried and what issues you got.

Comment: you can use `filter` or `map`? no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you really want, but providing you have array of items like `trackData` and you need only `year` component, it could be something like this?

```
var tracks = [trackData,
              //otherItems
]

tracks.forEach {
    $0.compactMap {$0.trackdate.year}.forEach {year in
        print(year)
    }
}
```

It this what you want? If you really need **specific** year(s), as you write, you would need to use something like `.filter({[2020,2023].contains($0)})` between `compactMap` and `forEach`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try it as follow

```
let array = [(id: UUID(), trackdate: DateComponents(year: 2021, month: 4, day: 2), tokencount: 2), (id: UUID(), trackdate: DateComponents(year: 2020, month: 8, day: 4), tokencount: 6)]
let lastYearData = array.filter({ $0.trackdate.year == 2020}) //This will give you all objects which has year 2020
let allYears = array.compactMap({ $0.trackdate.year })
print(allYears) //This will print all non-null years
```